# How to process a multi step form in controller? (When the user clicks "go to step 2" the form is not being processed in the controller)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a multi step form using bootstrap and jQuery. The multi step form is for a user to buy a product. There are 4 steps: Step 1 is for the user insert his info (name, email, etc), Step 2 the user select the payment method, Step 3 the user introduces the payment data, Step 4 present an invoice for the user. So Im trying to divide the form in 4 steps, each step with a respective method in the controller.

The issue is that when the user clicks in the submit input "Go to step 2"  the the jquery code shows the section of step 2 for the user select the payment methods, But the step 1 is not being processed in the PaymentController, that is, the request is not reaching the PaymentController.

Do you know where is the issue?

**The flow that I have for this issue:**

I created a PaymentController to handle the payment process.

The user clicks in a product and goes to the product details page. In the product details page the user select the quantities. So there is a select menu inside a form with this action "`<form method="post" action="{{route('products.storeProduct', ['id' => $product->id, 'slug' => $product->slug])}}`">".

The route for this form is:

```
Route::post('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeProduct',
    'as'   =>'products.storeProduct'
]);
```

The storeProduct method stores the product, get some info from db and then redirect the user to the products.payment route to present the payment page page:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function storeProduct(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
        ...
        return redirect(route('products.payment',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }

    public function presentPaymentPage(Request $request, $id, $slug=null){
      ...
        return view('products.payment',
            ['product' => $product, 'id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]);
    }
}
```

The route for the presentPaymentPage():

```
Route::get('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@presentPaymentPage',
    'as'   =>'products.payment'
]);
```

Then for the step 2 I created the two methods below in the PaymentController and two routes in web.php:

Two methods added in the PaymentController (for now dont have any content):

```
public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
    dd($request->all()); // dont shows nothing
}
public function presentPaymentMethods(Request $request, $id, $slug=null){

}
```

And the routes for the methods:

```
Route::post('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment/storeUserInfo', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeUserInfo',
    'as'   =>'products.storeUserInfo'
]);

Route::get('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment/paymentMethods', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@presentPaymentMethods',
    'as'   => 'products.presentPaymentMethods'
]);
```

In the payment.blade.php I have form steps like:

```
<div class="tab-content id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <form method="post" action="{{route('products.storeUserInfo', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug])}}">
            <!-- form fields -->
            <input type="submit" href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade clearfix" id="step2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
        <form method="post" class="clearfix">
            <!-- form fields -->
            <input type="submit" href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" class="next-step" value="Go To step 3"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that the multi-part form is only processed on the client side, and doesn't get returned to the server. I believe this is the expected behaviour of the tabs in Bootstrap.

The way you've set up your code, you've got two options here.

**Option 1: Process multi-part forms on the client side**

You can store all the required information on the page, either in a JS object or in hidden form fields (or even regular form fields). And at the final step, the `<input type="submit" ... />` button does the submit to the backend `PaymentController`.

*Pros:* Don't have to manage multi-part state on the backend.

*Cons:* You will need some way to check whether the products are available still. For example, if I click the submit button an hour or two later, are the products still available? Also, storing payment information somewhere on the client side may not be good practice because customers could be using public PCs.

**Option 2: Process multi-part forms on the back end**

Modify your view file so that you don't try to process the multi-step functionality purely on the client side in JS. This seems to be more in line with what you are trying to do since you have multiple actions on `PaymentController` that corresponds with each step.

To do this, simply remove the Bootstrap attributes, i.e. `role`, `data-toggle`, etc, and just use good 'ol `if/else` statements in the view to toggle the portion of the page to be displayed.

*Pros:* Seems to be less work since you've got everything set up to do this already (except your view file)

*Cons:* Requires a post-back each time the user clicks the button to go to the next step.

Hope this helps.